# Как поменять кодировку во Flash?

Tags: xml, flash

Есть XML документ, но когда ставлю русские буквы, то просто образуется пустое место, изначально буквы латинские. Пробовал настроить через Adobe Flash, но когда я делаю Debug, то текста вообще нет.

Ссылка на исходник внизу http://rghost.ru/39676134

Comment: Другой шрифт пробовали?

Comment: Ну, в исходнике надо поменять, но у меня компиляция нормально не проходит

Comment: Ставлю другой шрифт и все нормально работает, сам шрифт наверно битый.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, во флешке для текстового поля, отображающего ваши буквы, не подключен Cyrillic набор символов — только латиница. Может такое быть? По описанию похоже — латиница есть, кириллица - пустота. Подировка XML файла - UTF-8 же?

Comment: Да. Я пробовал подключать, но при компиляции у меня не отображается текст, который в xml